# Zend Framework: Can I set a depth for url parameters?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I would like to get only one parameter.
For `example site.ru/controller/action/param1/value/`

But if I request follow url:
`site.ru/controller/action/param1/value/param2/value2/param3/value4/`
by default I havn't any error.

**Is it possible to set up the depth for url parameters? Or I shuld do it manually via url parsing?**

Answer (score 1):

The default route allows any number of parameters after the `:module/:controller/:action` (or just `:controller/:action`) parts.

If you want to limit this, create your own route.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no limit on the amount of param => value pairs used in the URL.

However you can create your own custom routes if you want to restrict the URL parameters

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '/:controller/:action/:id',
            array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'index','id'=>''), //default values
            array('controller'=>'[a-zA-Z-]','action'=>'[a-zA-Z-]+','id'=>'([0-9]+)') //patterns to match values
);
```

This route will be triggered only if request consists of controller name, action name and number for id.
If any other parameters will be passed, route won't be triggered.